# WPF ItemsControl - with no ItemContainer

Tags: wpf, containers, itemscontrol

I'm wanting to override ItemsControl, such that it doesn't create a container for each item, but presents them as is.

Is this possible? either through a new derived type or xaml?

Edit : To further explain, I'm wanting to bind the Canvas attached properties in the data template, as opposed to doing it in the ItemContainerStyle, but for that to work, there would have to be no container, .. such that the Canvas looks directly at the Ellipse/Rectangle.

The reason being, that the values i want to bind to may not always have the same name, as in this case, the Left property is 'Left' for types of A, but 'X' for types of B.

Im aware that i can do this with Priority bindings in the ItemContainerStyle, but would prefer to set the bindings in the data template.

Is it possible?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:A}">
                <Ellipse Width="25" Height="25" Fill="Red"
                         Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}"/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:B}">
                <Rectangle Width="25" Height="25" Fill="Green"
                           Canvas.Left="{Binding X}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>

        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: What kind of item do you mean? Is it already a UI element? Otherwise you simply need a container.

Comment: A DataTemplate can only work if there is a ContentPresenter or a ContentControl as item container.

Comment: "the Left property is 'Left' for types of A, but 'X' for types of B". Why not just fix that? Presumably you have some control over types A and B? If not, why not just wrap them in a view model, as is standard in WPF MVVM?

Comment: Yeah, there are a few ways around it, but I was just curious as to whether it was possible